# Continuous Tikhonov Regularization for Deconvolution

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, regularization

I am trying to solve the following deconvolution problem where $g(s)$ is a known real valued function and has finite energy:

$$g(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}f(t)e^{-(t-s)^2/2}dt$$

Since the integral kernel is a difference kernel the solution is available via convolution theorem.

$$f(t) = F^{-1}\left[\frac{F[g](w)}{e^{-w^2/2}}\right]$$

where $F$ denotes the fourier transform.

Now on top of this I would like to impose finite energy condition on $f$, so I wrote the following regularized error minimization

$$\hat{f}=\text{argmin}_f \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[g(s) - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}f(t)e^{-(t-s)^2/2}dt]^2 ds+ \alpha\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(t)|^2dt\right)$$

I would like to show that:

$$\hat{f}(t) = F^{-1}\left[\frac{F[g](w)}{e^{-w^2/2}+\alpha}\right]$$

or something in the line of this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is broadly correct and the main step that you need is that the Fourier transformation is an isometry so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2 \, dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(\omega)|^2 \, d\omega $ (up to a factor of $2\pi$). So, Fourier transform the problem and you can write the objective in Fourier space. The result then follows straightaway.

Comment: Just doing a Fourier transformation right away without regularization is not very advisable in presence of noise.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. Write the objective function (of the regularised problem) in Fourier space, and solve for $F(\omega)$. In fact, a glance at the answer shows you that $F(\omega)=G(\omega)/[e^{-\omega^2/2} + a]$.

Comment: I think the answer is probably going to look like $F[K]G(w)/(F[K]F[K] + \alpha)$ where F[K] is the fourier of kernel, which resembles more the typical tikhonov regularized least squares formula.

Comment: @CowboyTrader No this is not good way to do it. You need more freedom for regularization and adding more information to avoid underdetermination.

Comment: Effectively all you're doing is this. You don't want to divide by $e^{-\omega^2/2}$ because it comes too close to zero (when $|\omega|$ large). But if you add a constant on to the denominator, then it becomes bounded away from zero. Job done. The same with any situation where you need to "divide" by a matrix $M$ whose eigenvalues might get close to zero: replace the matrix with $M+\epsilon I$.

Comment: No kind of noise? Thats just unrealistic fantasies...